# why my dropdown navigation bar doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I was trying to shorten the navbar code on w3schools' css tutorial(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar). But my dropdown menu doesn't appear properly. Why is that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a, span{
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-decoration:none;

}

.drop{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
display:none;

}

span:hover .drop{
display: block;


}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
    <span>Dropdown
      <a class="drop" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="drop" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="drop" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </span>
    
   

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've added your `.drop` class to a wrapper instead on the `a` tags themselves

Also I gave the `span` `position: relative` so the dropdown can be positioned underneath the menu item

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a, span{
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-decoration:none;
position: relative;
}

.drop{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
display:none;
flex-direction: column;
left: 0;
}

span:hover .drop{
display: flex;


}
```

```html
<a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
    <span>Dropdown
      <div class="drop">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </span>
    
   

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Comment: thanks but why we need to wrap anchors with div? why mine wont work? im confused

Comment: Well you made all of your `a` elements `position:absolute` so they all got the same position overlapping eachother. Now I only added the `absolute` to the wrapper so that all `a` elements inside keep their default position.
Hope this makes sense :)